# Как подключиться к VPN на виртуальной машине?

Tags: virtualbox, openvpn, виртуализация

Запускаю на гостевой машине (Linux) клиент OpenVPN и пытаюсь подключиться через VPN к серверам - ничего не выходит.
Вроде бы подключился успешно (консоль говорит: `Initialization Sequence Completed` ), но к нужному серверу не подключает. Хотя если я запущу подключение на хосте (Windows), то все работает.
Есть ли какие-то особенности использования VPN- подключения в виртуальной машине?
Что мне требуется сделать чтобы успешно подключиться?

[image: деловой кот]
[Картинка побольше](https://habrastorage.org/webt/60/91/80/609180171f599642692104.png)

Comment: нет, ни каких особенностей быть не должно... с виду всё подключается корректно... почему ты считаешь, что что-то не так? ЗЫ: текст лучше приводить текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: @Fat-Zer сейчас проверил - пинг до нужного хоста идет,
а через браузер по http доступа нет.
Как-то странно

Comment: с другх хостов доступ есть? «нет доступа» — это ошибка или соединение не устанавливается? в первом случае — дело скорей всего в настройках веб-сервера связанных с доменом. во втором — скорей всего в том, что сервер слушает только на каком-то конкретном, вероятно внешнем, адресе.